# AWS CDK: Can't define Content-Type in AWS API Gateway Integration Response

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a GET Response to my API Gateway with AWS CDK.
However, I get this Error when I do *cdk deploy*:

`Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Content-Type] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: f4b6ec17-f0ae-4e2a-aa18-b86ddcac807a; Proxy: null)`

My Code:

```
const admin = api.root.addResource('admin');
    admin.addMethod(
      'GET',
      new apigw.LambdaIntegration(hmtl_code, {
        passthroughBehavior: apigw.PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_MATCH,
        requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{"statusCode": 200}' },
        integrationResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: "200",
            responseParameters: {
              'method.response.header.Content-Type': "'text/html'"
            },
            responseTemplates: { "text/html": "$input.path('$')" }
          }
        ]
      }),
      {
        methodResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: "200",
          }
        ]
      }
    );
```

I tried it with a MockIntegration as well, but this Error message keeps popping up.
Help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly a bit late here, but I just ran into the same issue and wish the cdk error was clearer.

The parameters in `integrationResponses` needs to be defined as part of `methodResponses` too.

From the docs for [IntegrationResponse.responseParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.IntegrationResponse.html#responseparameters):

> The destination must be an existing response parameter in the MethodResponse property.

So applying that to your code...

```js
const admin = api.root.addResource('admin');
admin.addMethod(
  'GET',
  new apigw.LambdaIntegration(hmtl_code, {
    passthroughBehavior: apigw.PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_MATCH,
    requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{"statusCode": 200}' },
    integrationResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: '200',
        responseParameters: {
          'method.response.header.Content-Type': "'text/html'",
        },
        responseTemplates: { 'text/html': "$input.path('$')" },
      },
    ],
  }),
  {
    methodResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: '200',
        responseParameters: {
          // a required response parameter
          'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
          // an optional response parameter
          'method.response.header.Content-Length': false,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```